# Tradução incompleta no Tour do site

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

O cabeçalho do página do [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/about) está com algumas partes não traduzidas.

> Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e respostas para
>   **professional and enthusiast programmers**. Foi desenvolvido e é
>   administrado por você como parte da rede Stack Exchange de sites de
>   perguntas e respostas. Com a sua ajuda, trabalhamos em conjunto para
>   desenvolver uma biblioteca de respostas detalhadas para cada pergunta
>   sobre **programming**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Assunto relacionado: [Sobre partes do site em inglês](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/10/sobre-partes-do-site-em-ingles)

Comment: @bfavaretto Já que lá fala disso e até tem esse item específico em algum outro lugar, seria duplicata?

Comment: Acho que lá é mais genérico, preferi deixar esta questão como está. Até porque a resposta propõe uma tradução. @bigown

Answer (score 2):

Tradução correta:

> Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e respostas para
>   programadores profissionais e entusiastas. Foi desenvolvido e é
>   administrado por você como parte da rede Stack Exchange de sites de
>   perguntas e respostas. Com a sua ajuda, trabalhamos em conjunto para
>   desenvolver uma biblioteca de respostas detalhadas para cada pergunta
>   sobre programação.

Answer (score 1):

There was still a small untranslated word, which I just updated (the last *programação*)