# Página inicial tem tradução incompleta

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

O texto na página inicial ainda está com a tradução incompleta, similar ao reportado aqui (mas em um local diferente): [Tradução incompleta no Tour do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/92/traducao-incompleta-no-tour-do-site)

*Helping the developers: the initial page still has some text mixing English and Portuguese, similarly to what's reported here (but in a different place): [Tradução incompleta no Tour do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/92/traducao-incompleta-no-tour-do-site)*

> Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e respostas para **professional and enthusiast programmers**. É 100% gratuito e não requer registro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: Não consegui criar o bug com a tag internacionalização, conforme [orientação do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/92/traducao-incompleta-no-tour-do-site), pois a tag ainda não existe :(

*PS: I couldn't tag this question with the **internacionalização** tag as it had not been created yet (and I do not have > 150 rep to create a new tag)*

Comment: Já tem pelo menos três duplicatas deste relato... por favor, agilizem esta simples correção para evitarmos mais e mais duplicatas... obrigado.